# Why does UI show null after value has been assigned?

Tags: flutter

I'm changing the default starter app to retrieve a counter value that I set in a firebase database.

There's a variable that will hold the value of the counter that was retrieved from firebase.

When I restart the app, that value is null at first. Then when I increment the local counter variable, it displays the correct value that is stored in firebase.

[image]

The firebaseFunction runs and prints the two print statement to the console. But I don't know why the _firebaseCounter  value is null only the first time I run the app?

[image]

Edit: I have added another print for the value of _firebaseCounter. This is the debug console output after the restarting app.

[image]

Comment: The reason that print statement is showing null is because of where you have placed it. It is not going to wait for the future to finish before executing so it is null the on the first execution. Also please don't post code in pictures.

Comment: Is that why the initial value of the counter is null when the app is restarted?   Sorry about the code in pictures. I thought that was the clearest way to convey the question.

Comment: no I was just making observation on your placement of that print statement. move that print into the then block and see what you get